# Render Image on Controller

Tags: 8

I have a controller that renders page elements. I have a php variable of type png image. What is the proper way to render it?

My code:

```
public function buildPage() {

    $page = [];

    $block_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
    $config = [];
    $plugin_block = $block_manager->createInstance('my_custom_block', $config);


    $page['element_one'] = $plugin_block->build();

    $page['element_two'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->t('This is the second page element'),
    );

    //How to render this on a third page element?
    $image = 'test.png'

    return $page;
  }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the element using the image theme hook:

```
$page['element_three'] = [
  '#theme' => 'image',
  '#uri' => $image_path,
  '#alt' => $title,
  '#title' => $title,
  '#width' => $width,
  '#height' => $height,
];
```

Comment: Thank you Jaypan. This image comes from google chart api as an image. Should I save it first to my public or privete files first right? Thank you,

Comment: Depends on the project requirements. Too much variability to give a generic response to that question.

Comment: So.. It is possible to render a php image variable directly with the image theme hook without an specific url? Thank you,

Comment: Finally I noticed that doing the request with \Drupal::httpClient() returned a psr7 object. So i tried to directly use the google chart api url as the #uri array setting. Thank you very much.